# How to use linux eBPF to inject a packet into the kernel network stack?

Tags: linux-networking

I am trying to use an eBPF program and with an AF_XDP socket and a user-space filter program to filter ethernet packets arriving at a server. For this I need to arrange that packets which pass the filter are reinjected into the kernel network stack.
I am calling xsk_ring_prod__reserve and xsk_ring_prod__submit for these packets, but they do not get where I want them to go; I suspect they are being passed to the ethernet card for transmission but, I cannot confirm this directly.
I was hoping there would be an example as part of the Facebook Katran load balancer https://github.com/facebookincubator/katran ... surely load balancing sometimes involves accepting packets into the arrival node ... but I cannot see what I need.
My test case is here https://github.com/tjcw/xdp-tutorial/tree/master/udp-sender ; at the moment I am attempting to drop UDP packets and pass other protocols such as TCP and ICMP ; but I find that the test case drops all arriving packets when it it running.

Can anyone tell me how to do the packet injection ?

Answer (score 0):

From Magnus Karlsson, who wrote most of the relevant kernel code :

When you send packets with AF_XDP, they go out the network interface, not to the kernel. If there was such a thing as XDP for egress (there is only XDP for ingress now) you could have used it to forward the packets into the kernel. Now you are forced to use something like a tun/tap or a veth device to send the packet into the kernel. These devices are not that fast unfortunately. Maybe 1 Mpps.

If you need higher speeds than 1 Mpps and your filter/program is simple, then I would recommend implementing it in XDP as it runs in the kernel before the packet is transferred to the kernel or user-space. It will be faster than bouncing it up to user space first.

Hope this helped.

Comment: To Magnus : At the moment I am looking for function; after I get function I can think about performance. I am pushing the packets back in with tun, but finding that nothing gets delivered to the server application; I am using 'netcat' over UDP to avoid the need for session setup that TCP would have. 'tcpdump' shows that I am injecting cirrectly-formed packets to the tun, but the netcat listener isn't getting anything.